# Setting HTML textbox value using javascript function?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I'm using this code to set the HTML textbox value using Javascript function. But it seems to be not working. Can anyone point out, what is wrong with this code?

```
Whats your Name?
<input id="name" value="" />

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function setValue(value){
var myValue=value;
document.getElementsById("name").value = myValue;
}
</script>
```

the "value" is came from my android java class using this codes

```
String value = "Isiah";
    WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web1);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/webpage");
    web.loadUrl("javascript:setValue("+ value +")");
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("name").value = value`

Comment: What's with the extra `"` after `\"Javascript\">` ? (and the backslashes)

Comment: First you store the value passed to the function in a var (unnecessary) then try to overwrite it with a DOM element's value and do nothing more. I said "try" because [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName) returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCollection) and not a DOM element, let alone you don't have any element with that name. Use `getElementById` instead. Also, you don't ever call the function. It'd be better if you explicitly tell us what you're expecting your function to do.

Comment: It looks like your assignment is reversed

Comment: i edited my codes and it seems not working

Comment: You have a typo. `getElementsById` should be `getElementById` (without the extra **s**). Also the function is never called.

Comment: how can I call it without using a button?

Comment: If you found a solution, make sure you select an answer as the accepted one. You can answer your own question and select it if none of the answers given were helpful.

Answer (score 7):

```
   function setValue(value) {
    var myValue=value; //unnecessary
    document.getElementById("name").value= myValue;
}
```

But then as pointed out in the comments, you need to call setValue(value) somewhere in your code.  Right now you just defined the function is never called.

Comment: how can I call it without using a button?

Comment: You can use a button/link/or just call the function on page load. Depends on when you want the box to be filled. When do you want this to happen?

Answer (score 1):

You could either access the element’s value by its name:

```
  document.getElementsByName("textbox1"); // returns a list of elements with name="textbox1"
    document.getElementsByName("textbox1")[0] // returns the first element in DOM with name="textbox1"
```

So:

```
    input name="buttonExecute" onclick="execute(document.getElementsByName('textbox1')[0].value)" type="button" value="Execute" />
```

Or you assign an ID to the element that then identifies it and you can access it with getElementById:

```
    <input name="textbox1" id="textbox1" type="text" />
    <input name="buttonExecute" onclick="execute(document.getElementById('textbox1').value)" type="button" value="Execute" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not linking the function to anything. For example, a click:

```
<input id="name" value="" onclick="javascript:this.value=12;"/>
```

Replace the onclick attribute for your desired function, whatever it does (you need to be more specific)

Also, there is no language attribute (at least not anymore) use `type="text/javascript"` instead

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4juEp/

Click the input to see it working.

Look at this second fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/4juEp/1/

which loads whatever is defined in the hid input to the name input.

Comment: how can I call it without using a button?

Comment: @user1570222 I've never used Android (I plan to but I don't know any of it right now) See the link I updated to the answer, hope that it helps, as I said, you need call the function from somewhere. Take a lesson on javascript http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2ifWcnQs6M

Comment: @user1570222 Well, what exactly do you need? execute it when the page is loaded?

Comment: @user1570222 and where from do you take the input to the function? myValue in your example.

Comment: myValue = value.    "value" is came from my android java class

Comment: As I said, I don't know Android. You just have to replace that value for whatever you need. In the examples I provided there is enough information on how you need your javascript but I get the input directly from the DOM (Document Object Model) which is built from the html. If you manage to set the value on that hidden input ie. when you generate the html, the example will work as it is. What else do you need? are not useful the examples provided?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `document.getElementsById("name")` it should be `document.getElementById("name")`

not `Elements` it is `Element`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have a typo in your javascript function i.e. you have used `getElementsById` as compared to `getElementById`

To set the value of the textbox on page load, I suggest you use an alternative

```
<body onload="setValue('yourValueToSet');">

<!-- Your usual html code in the html file -->

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the quotes,

try,

```
web.loadUrl("javascript:setValue('"+ value +"')");
```

also consider about the typo.

Comment: I edited it to web.loadUrl("javascript:setValue('"+ value +"')"); still undefined

Comment: i'm not sure whether you are missing the html extension at the end of    `web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/webpage");` or try    `web.loadUrl("javascript:setValue(\""+ value +"\")");`

Comment: I already change it like what you said but still its undefined

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
<body onload="setvalue($value);">
Whats your Name?<input id="name" name="name" value=""/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setValue(value){
document.{formname}.name.value = value;}</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not Elements
It's Element

You should use `document.getElementById('object-id');`

Comment: Try to elaborate your answer. Like giving code or documentation etc.